# i/o from text file into variables

Tags: python

I've started running through some python again and I'm stuck, the code that i'll supply is trying to compare the right answer chosen by the user with a string read from a txt file. So next_line(the_file) will go and read one line from a txt file and put that line of text into the correct variable. The line of text that is read is only one character long and is always a number from 1-4.

```
correct = next_line(the_file)
     if correct:
       correct = correct [0]
```

The user will choose an answer from 1-4 with

```
answer = input("What's your Answer?:")
```

Then the program checks the answer with

```
if answer == correct:
   print ("Right!")
```

The thing I don't understand is why does `correct = next_line(the_file)` need to have the whole if statement correct = correct [0]?

If the user enters 4 into answer then why can't it just be checked against correct = next_line(the_file).

Comment: Are you sure that the program executes fine?

Comment: "The line of text that is read is only one character long". SO, *correct = correct[0]* is same with *correct = correct*. But "the user enters 4", I have no idea about it. Maybe you should check your codes.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: When the programme retrieves the string from the text file it places a number, lets say 3, into correct. Why does the if statement need to be run, what is kept inside correct[0]? 

If I take out the if statement then the programme doesn't keep score.

Comment: How is `next_line` defined?

Comment: You should print out what is being assigned to your `correct` variable, and print out its length. There may be control characters like new-lines or other things

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I've just stumbled across the same question that has been asked before. Here's the link to that answer. I didn't want to post the whole question because I thought it was too large but i'll do that next time.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264320/please-help-me-understand-this-code?rq=1

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The line of text that is read is only one character long and is always a number from 1-4.
>   The thing I don't understand is why does correct = next_line(the_file)
>   need to have the whole if statement correct = correct [0]?

This is because when you read the line from a file, you are reading the entire line, including the end of line character:

```
>>> i = '4\n'
>>> i[0]
'4'
```

That's why there is `correct = correct[0]`. The outside `if` statement makes sure that you skip any blank lines.

So, these lines:

```
correct = next_line(the_file)
if correct:
   correct = correct[0]
```

Translated mean:

"Read the next line from the variable `the_file` and store the result in `correct`. If there is a line read (that is, the line isn't a blank line), then store the first character from that line in the variable `correct`."

If you don't check the value of `correct`, then when there is an empty line in the file, you'll get an `IndexError` exception on `correct = correct[0]`.